# Launch ECR Docker image from AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-php-sdk, amazon-ecr

I host Docker images on AWS ECR and I'd like to run these images like this :

```
docker run --rm -i <image_name> <some parameters>
```

But using AWS API (through PHP SDK).

Is it possible to run a container like that (once or many at the same time) ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to launch a fargate task, you can use the runtask command from the api to do this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ecs-2014-11-13.html#runtask